# Input a matrix in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm just a beginner of `C++` and I want to write a program which inputs and then displays a matrix of order `i * j`. I have written the following program but it did not work.

Kindly guide me .

I think may be the method of accessing is not right or something like that.

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int i = 0,j = 0;

  cout << "Enter no of rows of the matrix";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "Enter no of columns of the matrix";
  cin >> j;

  float l[i][j];

  int p = 0, q = 0;

  while (p < i) {
    while (q < j) {
      cout << "Enter the" << p + 1 << "*" << q + 1 << "entry";
      cin >> l[p][q];

      q = q + 1;
    }
    p = p + 1;
    q = 0;
  }
  cout << l;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly doesn't work. If you get any unexpected output or an error message, copy and paste them to your question.

Comment: i did not get the required output

Comment: i want to print the matrix after input.

Comment: this is the output      0xbfa9f5b0

Answer (score 2):

you cant define an array with variable length. You need to define a dynamic arrays or std::vector

```
#include<vector>
std::vector<std::vector<int> > l(i, std::vector<int>(j, 0));
```

And `cout << l` will only print out the value of a `int**` . To print out each individual integer, you need to loop against each of them.

```
for(int x = 0; x < i; ++i){
   for(int y = 0; y < j; ++y){
     cout << l[x][y] << " "
   }
   cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Please don't do that. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @n.m. ok, c++ question has a c++ answer.

Comment: I didn't say not to use `std::vector`. If you can, always use it.

Comment: should be ++x (not ++i).

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code:
(instead of alloc its better to use new in c++, and use delete to free the memory)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;
int _tmain()
{
    int row,col;

cout<<"Enter no of rows of the matrix";
cin>>row;
cout<<"Enter no of columns of the matrix";
cin>>col;

float** matrix = new float*[row];
for(int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new float[col];
int p=0,q=0;

for(unsigned i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for(unsigned j=0;j<col;j++) {
        cout<<"Enter the"<<i+1<<"*"<<j+1<<"entry";
        cin>>matrix[i][j];
    }
}

for(unsigned i=0;i<row;i++) {
    for(unsigned j=0;j<col;j++) {
        cout<<matrix[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```